# iOS7: Tabbar not showing selectionIndicatorImage on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, tabbar

I have been setting a SelectionIndicatorImage for my tab bar since iOS 5 calling this on launch:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:image];
```

Now with iOS 7, when the app is first launched, the image is not showing anywhere (like if no tab was selected). After changing to another tab, it works properly.

Is this an iOS 7 bug or am I doing something wrong? Any idea for solving this?